# grafika continuous encode video with camera2 in background

Tags: android, android-camera2, grafika

I used grafika library to continuous encode video frames with old camera API.

Because the old camera API needs a visible `SurfaceView` to receive data from camera, so I'm trying to use camera2 to replace old camera API.

The camera2 API can use `ImageReader` to receive data without visible View, so I try to use `ImageReader` to repleace SurfaceView. But I face a strange problem that I **can not** do `createCaptureSession` successfully after I do `mDisplaySurface = WindowSurface(mEglCore, imageReader.surface, false)`
 from [grafika example](https://github.com/google/grafika/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/android/grafika/ContinuousCaptureActivity.java#L386)

There has no message from `onConfigureFailed` of `createCaptureSession`, so I don't know what happened with these.

Can someone help me figure it out? or tell me how to use camera2 to encode video's frame data?

Comment: You need to link to your code, because it's hard to tell how you've tried to update the grafika example for camera2.  There shouldn't be any need to pass the ImageReader Surface to a WindowSurface class, for example - it should just be directly passed to createCaptureSession.

Comment: You are right, I finally succeed by passing `mCircEncoder.getInputSurface()` to camera session instead of `WindowSurface` or `ImageReader `